# SWRevealViewController - Reveal not showing nav menu

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following [this](http://appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) tutorial and I'm at the point (about halfway down) where I add this bit of code to some sort of controller:

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

Now, I'm a little confused on where this piece of code goes. I currently have it in my "front" view (the one that shows when the menu is closed). However, when I click my menu button, nothing happens.

Here is what my current storyboard looks like (there is a white menu button left of "Home" on the home screen, hard to see):

[image]

And here is my current viewDidLoad function inside HomeViewController.Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            print("reveal")
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }


        if webView != nil {
            print("webview is not null")
            webView!.scrollView.bounces = false

            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("find_it_myself", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "assets/html/home")
            let serviceDeskPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ServiceDeskNumbers", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "assets/data")
            let serviceDeskData = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: serviceDeskPath!)
            let serviceCenterPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ITSC Live Room Locations", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "assets/data")
            let serviceCenterData = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: serviceCenterPath!)

            let newStr = NSString(data: serviceDeskData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let newerStr = NSString(data: serviceCenterData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            NSLog(String(webView!.URL))



            NSLog("path: " +  path!)
            let requestURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
            print("request is not null")
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL:requestURL)

            let theConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            theConfiguration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "interOp")

            webView!.loadRequest(request)
        }
        else{

            print("webview is null")
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my solution just in case. The reveal was actually working, but only with the sliding gesture, not by pressing the menu button.

I added a button press function for the menuButton, with a revealToggle function call to the library from the GitHub project (SWRevealViewController).

```
@IBAction func menuButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject){
        self.revealViewController().revealToggle(menuButton)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

All this code:

```
menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
```

means is that invoke method (revealToggle:) on RevealViewController, which means you should have a method in ReleavelViewController with that name and should do what you want to do there (if that's intended). Ideally you should have some thing like this:

```
menuButton.target = self
menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
```

And then:

```
func revealToggle(sender: AnyObject) {
    //present your view controller
    self.pushViewController(self.revealViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

It's very confusing what you are trying to do here. You'r revealVC shows navigation controller on some event and menu controller on some other event. From what you have explained it seems, your home controller is the one which presents revealVC but there doesn't seem to be a segue for that? Did you mean to make your navigation controller "initial controller"?

Comment: Did you check out the tutorial? The Reveal View Controller is supposed to be the opening View. I'm new to iOS development, so I couldn't tell you why exactly the tutorial does stuff the way it does, I'm just trying to follow it.