# SWRevealViewController sidebar is not presenting in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using **SWRevealViewController** in my project first time.
I follow [This](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) tutorial to do this.

**What i did:**

I added `SWRevealViewController.h` and `SWRevealViewController.m` in my project.

i import file in FirstViewController.h is like following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "SideBarTableViewController.h"//this is UITableViewController which i want to display when i click on menu button.
```

Add property for `Menu` button.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
```

In `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

But when i click on Menu button it shows nothing, whats the issue i occure??

Comment: Is everything is correct in Storyboard? I mean front, rear identifiers.

Comment: Yes @Amanpreet, actually it worked for me previously but i didn't get why it is not working currently?

Comment: :P you surely did anything. Check carefully.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731112/swrevealviewcontroller-reveal-not-showing-nav-menu

Comment: Yes i did it, @Amanpreet

Comment: check this link you get idea

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm doing in Objective C. it actually worked for me with same code but didn't get , why it not working currently

Comment: sidebarButton Is connected or not?

Comment: so what , understand the concept and write once in objective C

Comment: yes, @Amanpreet , it was connected not used in .m file anywhere , is any wrong in this?

Comment: `sideBarTableViewController` class is responsible for segue transmission and side bar navigation have you imported ?

Comment: Yes, i will try  @Anbu.Karthik and yes Vaibhav

Comment: `self.revealViewController = [SWRevealViewController new];` then remove `if (revealViewController)` statement..?

Comment: can you attach your project here